# Returning numbers assigned to names in descending order

Tags: r, function

I want to compute a function say 'name_sort' that takes the input **names**  and **values**. The function should return the names from the second input - in decreasing order.

Thus values 3 2 1   should return the output **A B and C**

I am fairly new to R, so I am really struggling to wrap around my head if I am supposed to use an **if** statement or not. Any help would be much appreciated!

This is how I would like to start my statement:

```
names_sort <- function(values,names):
```

And this is the desired output

`names_sort(c(3,1,2), c("A","B","C"))` should return:

```
 [1] "A" "C" "B"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `[` on `order`ing of values in descending

```
names_sort <- function(values, names) {names[order(-values)]}
```

-testing

```
> names_sort(c(3,1,2), c("A","B","C"))
[1] "A" "C" "B"
```

Comment: @Kash I updated the post.  maybe you were using my old one

Comment: Hi Akrun! Thank you very much. Concerning the code you used "-" for values does that essentially mean "descending"?

Comment: You can use `decreasing = TRUE` in `order` as well

Comment: Where exactly would that need to go? Inside the brackets?

Comment: @Kash it would be `names[order(values, decreasing = TRUE)]`